# Check: Show that the set $\{e^{\pi ixn}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set $\{e^{\pi ixn}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not linearly independent in $L^2(0,1)$ by showing that there exist nonzero constants $\{c_n\}$ for which $e^{\pi ix}=\sum c_ne^{2\pi ixn}$.

If the set is not orthonormal then it isn't linearly independent. So assume that it is orthonormal. We will then find a contradiction such that it will show our assumption is wrong.

First we will show that $\langle e_n,e_m \rangle =1$ when $n=m$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 e^{\pi ixn}e^{2\pi ixm}\,dx & =\int_0^1 e^{\pi ix(n-2m)}\,dx=\int_0^1e^{-\pi ixn}\,dx \\
& =\int_0^1\,cos(-\pi ixn)+i\,sin(-\pi ixn)\,dx \\
& =\frac{1}{-\pi ixn}(\,sin(-\pi ixn)-i\,cos(-\pi ixn))]_0^1=0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Hence the set isn't orthonormal nor linearly independent.

Comment: If you get a 0 at the end, doesn't that mean that the set *is* an orthogonal set of vectors?  You said you would get $1$ but instead you get $0$. Also, the general proof strategy in the second paragraph is somewhat confusing. A linearly independent set may not be orthonormal, so the first sentence there is false...

Comment: How would I prove that it is not linearly independent?

Comment: To prove that it is not linearly independent, you have to show that one of the elements in the set is a linear combination of some of the others. That's what the problem asks you to do when it has you show that $e^{\pi i x} = \sum c_n e^{2\pi n i x}$.

Comment: Well I know that if the constant is linear then it is orthonormal

Comment: *"If the set is not orthonormal then it isn't linearly independent"*.  This is false.

Comment: Your dot product on $L^{2}_{(0,1)}$ is quite strange. Usually it's $\int_{0}^{1} u(x) \overline{v(x)} \; {\rm dx}$. And I don't know why you've decided that this set is linear dependent when it's orthogonal and thus linear independent.